# How to read data from a XML file and display it in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read data from xml file and display it over the text box in delphi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090582/how-to-read-data-from-xml-file-and-display-it-over-the-text-box-in-delphi-langua)

I am new to delphi ,and here i have an xml file called test.xml that looks like this

```
<data>
<vehicle>
    <type>Car</type>
    <model>2005</model>
    <number>1568</number>
</vehicle>
<vehicle>
    <type>Car</type>
    <model>2009</model>
    <number>1598</number>
</vehicle>
</data>
```

Here i want to display all the data in delphi while loading the form.Please help me by giving the complete code.Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this question [How to read data from xml file and display it over the text box in delphi language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090582/how-to-read-data-from-xml-file-and-display-it-over-the-text-box-in-delphi-langua) , even has the same sample data of your question.

Answer (score 0):

check
this out n see if it helps

[Swissdelphi center](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2162)

[About.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/ss/xml_rss_read_4.htm)

or try this also
[stack overflow Delphi XML traversing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968467/delphi-xml-traversing)